# Calling custom COM- or .Net-based library from Adobe Acrobat/Reader JavaScript

Tags: acrobat, adobe-reader, acrobat-sdk

is it possible to extend javascript object model in Acrobat/Reader? For example, is it possible to call a custom COM- or .Net-based library from Acrobat/Reader using javaScript. Or is their a diffrent way to develop and call custom libs?

Thanks
CommanderPeek